# Boost unit test appears to skip code that should be executed

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

It seems that the Boost test below is not working as I would expect.
Breakpoints show that the code within `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(...)` is not run (but the line with `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(..)` is run OK). What's wrong?

#### UT_Math.cpp

```
#include "../UTest/UT_Math.h"
#include <iostream>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(testUTMath)
{
    UTMath test;
    cout << "UTMath is started" << endl;
    test.Test1();
    cout << "Test1 is completed" << endl;
}
```

#### UT_Math.h

```
#include "../Math/Math.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE UTMathTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

class UTMath 
{
public:
   void Test1()
   {
      BOOST_REQUIRE(1==1);
   }
};
```

P.S.: What directives should be used for switching between Normal/UnitTest modes (for Windows and Unix)?

Comment: So why does the code inside the test case is not run? Have I done all required? As far I understand the `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` is run automatically (it doesn't require special `main()` func)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `main()` function has fixed the issue